# How do we take a backup of Elasticsearch indexes and restore using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

How can we take backup and restore? I have checked out few libraries and I'm not able to take backup properly and restore.

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use **Elasticsearch Curator**, which is a python cli/lib to handle many maintenance operations in elasticsearch, such as snapshot and restore:
https://github.com/elastic/curator

See usage options here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/singleton-cli.html